# Linq query may be null property is not

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nullable

I have a property that is **NOT** null (it's a PK). But I have a query that uses a LEFT JOIN in that table, creating the possibility of **null values**

**LINQ**

```
(from a in dbContext.TableA
join b in dbContext.TableB on a.IdB equals b.IdB into bLeft
from bTbl in bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    IdBTemp = bTbl.IdB, // This value may be null
    IdATemp = a.IdA
}.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new DynamicClassModel()
{
    // Stuff here (convertion to string, concatanations and other stuff)
});
```

**Class Model **

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[Column("IdB")]
public long IdB { get; set; }
```

---

*This is just an small query example. My query is larger than that, and there are more left joins, also there are more fields that are Not Mapped as null, but they may be null in this query.*

---

I was reading about [LET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231164/Into-and-let-in-LINQ-Let-vs-Into), also tried to fill the null value with some value (like 0).

**How can I pass a null value into a property not null?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to fill it with a default value of 0:

```
(from a in dbContext.TableA
join b in dbContext.TableB on a.IdB equals b.IdB into bLeft
from bTbl in bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    IdBTemp = bTbl == null ? 0 : bTbl.IdB,
    IdATemp = a.IdA
}.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new DynamicClassModel()
{
    // Stuff here (convertion to string, concatanations and other stuff)
});
```

But perhaps you want to use a `int?` instead. In that case use this:

```
(from a in dbContext.TableA
join b in dbContext.TableB on a.IdB equals b.IdB into bLeft
from bTbl in bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    IdBTemp = bTbl == null ? (int?)null : bTbl.IdB,
    IdATemp = a.IdA
}.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new DynamicClassModel()
{
    // Stuff here (convertion to string, concatanations and other stuff)
});
```

Comment: When I tried it I didn't try using **`(int?)`** going to try it.

Comment: That works like a charm =D Thanks, and thanks for the quickest replay that I have got in SO =P

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the default value as you want it to be: `bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` or `bLeft.DefaultIfEmpty(-1)`

Comment: O.o Ok, I'm felling very noob right now. I didn't knew that it was possible to do it like this =X Going to test it too =)

Comment: It's an entity not a property alone =( I need to declare something like `new TableBClass()`

Comment: That's totally up to you what you want as a default value in case if there is none.
Or just do IdBTemp nullable in the anonymous type you select.

Comment: +1 the tip is amazing. The correct one goes to @p.s.w.g but, TYVM =)

Comment: @Michel FYI you'd have to use `bLeft.Select(x => x.IdB).DefaultIfEmpty(0)`